# Reactjs - SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following code for my app component in reactjs:

```
function App() {
  var [expression, setExpression] = useState("");
  var [result, setResult] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">

    <div id="equals">
{result}
    </div>
<div id="display">
{expression}

</div>
<button id='zero' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "0")}>0 </button>
<button id='one' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "1")}>1 </button>
<button id='two' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "2")}>2 </button>
<button id='three' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "3")}>3 </button>
<button id='four' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "4")}>4 </button>
<button id='five' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "5")}>5 </button>
<button id='six' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "6")}>6 </button>
<button id='seven' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "7")}>7 </button>
<button id='eight' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "8")}>8 </button>
<button id='nine' onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "9")}>9 </button>
<button id="add" onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "+")}>+</button>
<button id="subtract" onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "-")}>-</button>
<button id="multiply" onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "*")}>*</button>
<button id="divide" onClick={() => setExpression(expression + "/")}>/</button>
  <button id="equals" onClick={() => setResult(eval(expression))}>=</button>
    </div>

  );
}
```

But when I open the browser I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
```

I don't know how to fix it though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's most likely coming from `eval(expression)`. But we have no way of knowing what `expression` is but it likely contains something like `08` (number preceded by zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit subtle. The issue is that you're concatenating strings. At some point, it would appear you've clicked the `0` button followed by any of the other digit buttons. That means you end up with `expression` being `"01"` or similar. That's a legacy octal literal, which (as you've discovered) are disallowed in strict mode.

You'll need to update your code that adds to the expression so that when it's about to add the digit 1 through 9, it looks to see if there's a `0` (and only a `0`) after the last operator and, if so, removes that `0` before adding the digit.

For instance, if `expression` is `"1+0"`, clicking `2` should remove that `"0"` before adding the `"2"` so that it ends up being `"1+2"`, not `"1+02"`.

Comment: This solves but one of the problems this code has. It just builds up a string and evaluates it as JS but at no point it tries to make it *valid* JS or anything like that. So you could type in `2++` and get a cryptic error as a result. Or get other strange results from combining these characters in various strings that might even happen to be valid JS but not a mathematical formula. `2-+-3` is valid JS (`2 - (+(-3)`) that returns `5`. But I wouldn't expect this from a calculator.

Comment: @VLAZ - 'Tis true, but it's the problem the OP asked about. Sometimes I refrain from questioning the entire context of the code in the question. :-D I assume in this case it's a simple learning assignment, not meant to be all that robust with its input...